# Angular/Firebase redirect to Login page after password change?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

Hello I'm using Angular and Firebase for the authentication. I have a short question

Does anyone know how to make the prompt redirect to the login page after successfully resetting password?

- I have a forgot password page which then asks for the email
- And then a link will be sent to the email which will ask the user for a new password

The two mentioned above are successfully configured, however I am having a hard time on how to implement the redirect to login page after changing password successfully

[The page only stays here after the password change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSV6x.png)

Authservice.ts password reset method

```
  resetPassword(email: string) {
    return this.afAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
      .catch(error => throw error); 
  }
```

Forgotpassword-component.ts

```
async resetPassword() {
    this.clearMessages();
    this.isClicked = true;
    this.actionButtonLabel = "Please wait...";
    await this.authService.resetPassword(this.userName).then(() => {
      this.actionButtonLabel = "Reset Password";
      this.alert.code = '200';
      this.alert.message = "A password reset link has been sent to your email address.";
      this.alert.status = 'success';
    }).catch(err => {
      this.isClicked = false;
      this.actionButtonLabel = "Reset Password";
      this.alert.code = err.code;
      this.alert.message = FirebaseErrors.Parse(err.code);
      this.alert.status = 'failed';
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass a URL to the sendPasswordResetEmail() function, like this:

```
 resetPassword(email: string) {
    return this.afAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email, {url: "http://example.com/login"}); 
  }
```

Also don't return a promise and attempt to catch it at the same time, you should allow whatever calls resetPassword() to handle the error.

Documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/passing-state-in-email-actions#passing_statecontinue_url_in_email_actions

Alternatively, you can create your own landing pages so that you have more control:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler

Comment: Hello! Upon entering the function that you put, I get an error after putting my email address that will send me a password reset link


**Edit: It shows an error if I put the login page of my web app (the firebase link) but works totally fine if I put the localhost login page**